# How to use sortby with paginate in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, laravel-4

Recently, I tried to order data by using appends attribute. From this code and it works.

```
    $data = $data->sortBy(function($each){
        return $each->total;
    });
```

Then I want to use it with my old pagination code as below.

```
    $data = Book::where("type", $type_id)->orderBy("id","desc")->paginate(10);
```

The way I want is order data by `total` attribute and then paginate it.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

try this [ I didn`t test it]:

```
 $data = Book::where("type", $type_id)->orderBy("total")->paginate(10);
```

Comment: It cant be this one because `total` is an appends attribute (virtual field not stored in database)

Comment: you can only use paginate() method with the query builder or an Eloquent model like laravel Doc http://laravel.com/docs/pagination